# Android BroadcastReceiver not working when app is installed from play store

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play, broadcast

I have a service that is getting battery updates via Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED:

```
batteryFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
batteryReceiver = new BatteryReceiver();
```

and the receiver:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String action = intent.getAction();
    if(action.equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED)) {
        onBattery = false;
        Log.w("battery","on power");
    }
    else if(action.equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED)) {
        Log.w("battery","on battery");
        onBattery = true;
    }
}
```

This works exactly as expected when the app is installed via USB debugging.  After I published this to the play store and did a fresh install from there, it doesn't work.  Other receivers aren't working in the app either.  The rest of the app appears to be working properly, just no broadcast receivers are working.  What could cause this to happen?

This is android 2.2 and it is an update to an app that was already in the store, the receiver was working properly before the update also.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running on Android 3.1+, and you did not run one of your components manually (e.g., start an activity from the launcher), none of your manifest-registered `BroadcastReceiver`s will work.

Comment: This is on Android 2.2, and it is an update to an existing app so it was already manually launched once.  These receivers also aren't registered in the manifest, rather setup via IntentFilter in code.  The receivers worked before this update... (and of course work properly over usb debugging).

Comment: @user1596144: How do you know that your service is running?

Comment: I use startForeground and the notification is showing in the upper left.  All other aspects of the app are working correctly.

Comment: @user1596144: Then unless there's something wrong that is causing your service to not go through the code paths that register the receivers, I have no explanation of your symptoms.